# Cannot get small caps with OTF font and XeTeX

Tags: xetex, plain-tex, small-caps, opentype

I am working on a project which requires me to use plain TeX, which I compile with XeTeX.

The font I use is available as the following OTF files: `MyFontSerif-{Regular,Bold,Italic,BoldItalic}.otf`

I am able to use them with the following commands:

```
\font\rm="MyFont Serif Regular"
\font\bf="MyFont Serif Bold"
\font\it="MyFont Serif Italic"
%%%
\rm{} my \bf{} beautiful \it{} text
```

However, I don't know how to recreate the `\sc{}` command, as there is no dedicated OTF file for that, and Google hasn't helped me so far.

Any solution or pointer will be appreciated.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the solution thanks to this amazing resource: http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/lgc2/xetexmain.pdf

```
\font\rm="MyFont Serif"
\font\bf="MyFont Serif/B"
\font\it="MyFont Serif/I"
\font\sc="MyFont Serif:+smcp"
```